# Display images from folder in 5 columns

Tags: php, image, upload

Hi I am viewing files from a folder which I want to delete, this works fine now but the images are in one list, I would like to display the images in 5 columns, I have tried adding a table but cant get it to work at all, any ideas? this is my code

```
<form id="stallionidelete" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
$dir = dirname(__FILENAME__)."/images/gallery" ;
$files1 = scandir($dir);
foreach($files1 as $file) {
    if(strlen($file) >=3) {
        $foil = strstr($file, 'jpg'); // As of PHP 5.3.0
        $foil = $file;
        $pos = strpos($file, 'css');
        if ($foil==true) {
            $i == ++$i;
            echo '<table><tr>';
            echo '<div class="gimage_'.$i.'"><input type="checkbox" id="gimage_'.$i.'" name="filenames['.$i.'][]" value="'.$foil.'" />';
            echo "<img width='150' height='150' src='images/gallery/$file' /><br/></div>";
            echo '</tr></table>';
            // for live host
            //echo "<img width='130' height='38' src='/ABOOK/SORTING/gallery-dynamic/images/gallery/$file' /><br/>";
        }
    }
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="mysubmit2" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you should doing the code

```
    <form id="stallionidelete" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <table border='1' width='546' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' bordercolor="#E1F5FF">
<tr>
            <td>
            <table  summary='table' style="width: 797px">
    <thead id="start">
        <tr>
            <th width='150' style="height: 40px">Image1</th>
            <th width='150' style="height: 40px">image2</th>
             <th width='150' style="height: 40px">Image3</th>
            <th width='150' style="height: 40px">image4</th>
             <th width='150' style="height: 40px">image5</th>

            </tr>
    </thead>
        <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
<tr>

        <?php
        $dir = dirname(__FILENAME__)."/images/gallery" ;
        $files1 = scandir($dir);
        foreach($files1 as $file){
        if(strlen($file) >=3){
        $foil = strstr($file, 'jpg'); // As of PHP 5.3.0
        $foil = $file;
        $pos = strpos($file, 'css');
        if ($foil==true){
        $i == ++$i;
        echo '<td bgcolor="#F7F7F7" width="183">';
        echo '<div class="gimage_'.$i.'"><input type="checkbox" id="gimage_'.$i.'" name="filenames['.$i.'][]" value="'.$foil.'" />';
        echo "<img width='150' height='150' src='images/gallery/$file' /><br/></div>";
        echo '</td>';
         // for live host
        //echo "<img width='130' height='38' src='/ABOOK/SORTING/gallery-dynamic/images/gallery/$file' /><br/>";
        }
        }
        }?>
        </table>
    </tr>  
        </tbody>
    </table></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
        <input type="submit" name="mysubmit2" value="Delete">
```

you dont have to echo table also you forget to put `<td>tag</td>`

i want to short cut  the misunderstand here can you basic check this and tell me if this what you need ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried, but still in one column :-(
http://www.jayg.co.uk/gallery6/upload_gallery.php

Comment: you want them in vertical columns ?

Comment: like 12345<br>
     678910<br>
     etc

Comment: and i check your website they are in separated `<td>` i think you mean how to do this in vertical columns right ?

Comment: Apologies, yes 5 in a row then onto next line

Comment: question updated test and tell me if that what you need

Comment: thanks :-) I have a syntax error on
   echo '<div class="gimage_'.$i.'"><input type="checkbox" id="gimage_'.$i.'" name="filenames['.$i.'][]" value="'.$foil.'" />';

Comment: `filenames['$i'][]//there is empty brackets what that for  ?`

Comment: try the code now i forget and put single quotes in first echo

Answer (score 0):

I think something like the following would help.

```
$dir = dirname(__FILENAME__)."/images/gallery" ;
$files1 = scandir($dir);

if ($files1) {

    echo '<table>';
    $fileCount = 0;
    foreach($files1 as $file){

        if(strlen($file) >=3 && strstr($file, 'jpg')){

            if ($fileCount % 4 == 0) {
               if ($fileCount > 0) {
                   echo '</tr>';
               }
               echo '<tr>';
            }

            echo '<td>
                     <input type="checkbox" id="gimage_'.$i.'" name="filenames['.$i.'][]" value="'.$foil.'" />
                     <img width="150" height="150" src="images/gallery/'.$file.'" />
                  </td>';

            $fileCount++;
        }
    }
    if ($fileCount > 0){
        if ($fileCount % 4 > 0){
            echo '<td colspan="'.($fileCount%4).'"></td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';      
    }
    echo '</table>';

    echo '<input type="submit" name="mysubmit2" value="Delete">';
}
```

Comment: Care to share which line ?

Comment: echo '<td colspan="'.$fileCount % 4.'"></td>';

Comment: Thanks, its getting there, no images though in the table
http://www.jayg.co.uk/gallery6/upload_gallery2.php

Comment: Image placed. I'll leave it to you for the fine tuning ;)

Comment: Only issue is, when I tryto delete the image it stays there :(

Comment: How about you place the <form> </form> inside <td></td>

Comment: When I try to delete, nothing happens now, I have put the code ive changed now here
http://www.jayg.co.uk/gallery6/upload_gallery2.php